# How to format the data using jspdf, i want 1st column in bold?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jspdf

How to format the data using jspdf, i want  1st column in bold, and the second column in normal text, want to align it in the middle of the pdf output.
Also i want a different colour for the first column in pdf and another color in 2nd column.

This is my code now-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>success</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function tableToJson(table) {
    var data = [];

    // first row needs to be headers
    var headers = [];
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,'');
    }
    data.push(headers);
    // go through cells
    for (var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++) {

        var tableRow = table.rows[i];
        var rowData = {};

        for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++) {

            rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;

        }

        data.push(rowData);
    }       

    return data;
}
function callme(){
var table = tableToJson($('#table-id').get(0));
var doc = new jsPDF('l','pt','letter',true);

doc.setFont("courier");
doc.setFontType("italic");
 margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
$.each(table, function(i, row){
  $.each(row, function(j,cell){

  if(j=="startdate" | j==2){
   doc.cell(5,20,290,20,cell,i);  
  }
  else{
    doc.cell(5,20,290,20,cell,i);
  }

  });
});

doc.save('Safaa.pdf');
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>form value</p>

<div class="container" id="pdf">  
<a href="javascript:genPDF()">Download PDF</a>
     {{#each arrayofpromotion}}        
  <table id="table-id" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>StartDate</th>
        <td> {{StartDate}} </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>EndDate</th>
        <td>{{EndDate}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>promotionId</th>
        <td>{{PromotionId}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>ArticleNo</th>
        <td>{{ArticleNo}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>PromotionsubsAdjID</th>
        <td>{{PromotionsubsAdjID}}</td>
      </tr >
      <tr>
        <th>promotionNameEN</th>
        <td>{{PromotionNameEN}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>promotionNameFR</th>
        <td>{{PromotionNameFR}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>LedgerDesc</th>
        <td>{{LedgerDesc}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>LedgerDescFR</th>
        <td>{{LedgerDescFR}}</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
   {{/each}}
   <a href="javascript:callme()">Call Me</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>


[Right now i am getting this type of Output][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

To change color:

```
doc.setTextColor(15, 15, 15);
```

To change font weight:

```
doc.setFontType("bold");
```

To align text:

```
doc.text('your text', 150, 255, 'center');
```

Comment: HOw to add bold only to the first column, and also the color.

Comment: You change to bold as i mentioned, add the text, then `doc.setFontType("normal");` next text will be normal. Same with color, change color to whatever u want, add text, then change back to black.

Comment: `setFontType` is not available in library